# A way to toggle between a sprite's animations in the Phaser framework

Tags: javascript, animation, phaser-framework

Is there a way to toggle between a sprite's animations? For example, I have a sprite touching the ground, but when it leaves the ground, I want it to play a different animation than the one that it plays while on the ground. However, I also want it to play the the first animation when it touches the ground again. I basically want something like this:

```
if (sprite.body.touching.down === false) {
    sprite.animations.toggleAnimation("different_animation");
} else {
    sprite.animations.play("original_animation");
}
```

Does Phaser have an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I've found a solution to this; what I've been needing to do is load a different **texture** onto the sprite, not necessarily play a different animation. I guess I didn't communicate that very well. Basically, what I'm saying is this example:

http://phaser.io/examples/v2/animation/change-texture-on-click

Answer (score 5):

You can add as many animations to a Sprite as you need and then play them using the key. For example:

```
sprite.animations.add('jump', [0,1,2,3]);
sprite.animations.add('crouch', [4,5]);
sprite.animations.add('walk', [6,7,9,10,11]);
```

Then you can just play the animations by their key: `sprite.play('walk')`

Comment: I figured out the answer to this; I was trying to load a different texture, not necessarily play a different animation. You can see it in my answer below. Thanks for the help, though :)

Answer (score 0):

to make things easy my approch is:

```
 animation_arr = ['idle', 'walk', 'jump', 'idle_towel', 'walk_towel', 'jump_towel' ];
 for(var i=0; i < animation_arr.length; i++){
    player.animations.add(animation_arr[i], [0+(i*10), 1+(i*10), 2+(i*10), 3+(i*10), 4+(i*10), 5+(i*10), 6+(i*10), 7+(i*10), 8+(i*10), 9+(i*10)], 10, true);
 }
```